# Подскажите как загрузить картинку (скриншот) в программу?

Tags: java, screenshots, скриншот

Подскажите как загрузить картинку (скриншот) в программу?

Конкретно есть скриншот (от экрана до области экрана) и его нужно загрузить в программу.

2ой вопрос - разбить на байты  (типа pixel grabber) и как делать анализ потом что бы находил нужные пикселя в скриншоте.

заранее спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

- [javax.imageio.ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) - умеет грузить картинки как объекты [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)
- javax.swing.JLabel - умеет отображать иконки
- javax.swing.ImageIcon - умеет загружать картинки как иконки

BufferedImage - там есть методы манипуляции с пикселями, а вот как проводить анализ - уже сложнее